# How to add discount field to the pricebook object in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, crm

I m new to salesforce platform.here I m doing a sample application of product marketing where i need to  create different discounts for different products in different regions.so for this i m thinking to create pricebooks for different regions which provides list price for all the products along with this i want to add discount field but i m not able to find how to add....In this the correct procedure or i have to take a custom object for region ???

how can i implement this discounts for different  regions...???

please provide your valuable suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of now Price Book is customizable but price book entry in not customizable, but soon than enhancement is going to launch ref : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007FDEAA2

I believe you need to find an alternate approach for the time being. You can you custom objects. Let me know some information about the requirements, I will help you out with more detail solution.